# Android java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android and I got the following error.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition

This is the code I added before the error.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{25.0f, 25.0f}, 0));
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(getActivity()).paint(paint).build());
```

What import should I use?

Comment: Did you have android support v7 widget as a library?

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle add this line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) how to use RecyclerView

Comment: If you are going to suggest a dependency, make sure it is the latest, `22.2.0`.

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows I edit my answer, I don't remember the last version and I answered from my phone.

Comment: hi i am facing a similar kind or error                                                      **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/data/com.dovezeal.gapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-v4-r7_6455648c9de399318a02085a4f76c6431b0bc412-classes.dex)**